# How to generate private key from modulus and exponent?

Tags: node.js, rsa, private-key, subtlecrypto

Having this code:

```
const { subtle } = require("crypto");
const getPem = require("rsa-pem-from-mod-exp");
const Token = require("jsonwebtoken");

async function createKeys() {
  const keyPair = await subtle.generateKey({
    name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
    modulusLength: 2048,
    publicExponent: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]),
    hash: "SHA-256"
  }, true, ["sign", "verify"]);
  const privateKey = await subtle.exportKey("jwk", keyPair.privateKey);
  const priv = getPem(privateKey.n, privateKey.d).replace(/public/gi, "PRIVATE")
  const pub = getPem(privateKey.n, privateKey.e);
  return { priv, pub };
}
// createKeys().then(k => console.log(`priv:\n\n${k.priv}\n\npub:\n\n${k.pub}\n\n`));

const payload = { id: 1 };
createKeys().then(k => {
  const signed = Token.sign(payload, k.priv, { algorithm: "RS256", keyid: "1" });
  console.log(signed);
  const verified = Token.verify(signed, k.pub, { algorithms: "RS256", complete: true });
  console.log(verified);
})
```

gives:

```
node:internal/crypto/sig:131
  const ret = this[kHandle].sign(data, format, type, passphrase, rsaPadding,
                            ^

Error: error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported
    at Sign.sign (node:internal/crypto/sig:131:29)
    at Object.sign (/home/shepherd/Desktop/test/express/node_modules/jwa/index.js:152:45)
    at Object.jwsSign [as sign] (/home/shepherd/Desktop/test/express/node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js:32:24)
    at module.exports [as sign] (/home/shepherd/Desktop/test/express/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js:204:16)
    at /home/shepherd/Desktop/test/express/crypto/c.js:21:24 {
  opensslErrorStack: [
    'error:0688010A:asn1 encoding routines::nested asn1 error',
    'error:0688010A:asn1 encoding routines::nested asn1 error',
    'error:068000A8:asn1 encoding routines::wrong tag',
    'error:0688010A:asn1 encoding routines::nested asn1 error',
    'error:068000DF:asn1 encoding routines::too large'
  ],
  library: 'DECODER routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.6.0
```

But the keys seems find:

```
priv:

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----


pub:

-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEAq8G7V/OWIpwfM9wKailp9uB7GgYEywq5I5mW9vMfB7vndD1gzIWt
EyADeS/Dx5Yxq9LNSgvsltO5ZaQITuNBSVEJFZ6/aT9nG5zrH9QpqGXKNipcLjMc
SVYyc0ybXWHNbawZe0pWOqSVz5wja+H+9+JN8U//DsZZTe61wzc1tdRooMf4eQEh
Q49dwErrMunBinF35vDcJgkY4nzND3CxnALEdRYf34aYkuCLi5G11UUrHUoGN4di
9I+NVGIhj4Do9d6BvnsHDCSN5BTAFribe0y7AvqTgCD9JMb2OIqd+z3m+tjk+V64
yOOaHQEMKeRr5eDIxa2QD6FfK3Gpqmu5pQIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Those key `console.log`ed from above by uncommenting it. So if the keys seems to be ok, whats the problem? The RSA routine says `error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported`, but why?

PS: I need n, e variables to publish in OIDC discovery `jwks_uri`. So i need library which provides these variables. Subtle library does.

Comment: Your private key is invalid, which you can see e.g. with `openssl rsa -check -in <path to pem> -noout`.

Comment: Why do you use the WebCrypto API under NodeJS for key generation and PEM export instead of the more convenient [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) module?

Comment: Because I need n, e, d variables as to to public n and e for OIDC `jwks` endpoint. And subtle library can provide me these variables

Comment: (1) mathematically RSA privatekey can be (n,d) but _PEM format_ "RSA PRIVATE KEY" is CRT-form defined in [RFC8017 A.1.2 et pred](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#appendix-A.1.2) which your code doesn't even remotely do. (2) Since nodejs v15.9, builtin-crypto.keyObject.export supports 'jwk' format which gives what you actually want, but didn't ask about.

Comment: The *node-rsa-pem-from-mod-exp* library you are using seems to support only public keys, but not the more complex private keys. How about the following alternative: Create the keys and export them as PEM (for signing/verifying with *jsonwebtoken*). Convert PEM to JWK (to extract n,d,e), or export again as JWK as mentioned in the prevoius comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in my comment, the posted private key is invalid. This can be checked e.g. with

```
openssl rsa -check -in <path to pem> -noout
```

The reason for this is that the *private* key is incorrectly converted with `getPem()`, since the [*rsa-pem-from-mod-exp*](https://github.com/tracker1/node-rsa-pem-from-mod-exp) library only supports *public* keys.

---

An alternative is to generate PEM encoded keys with *crypto*, which can be used for signing and verifying with *jsonwebtoken*:

```js
var crypto = require("crypto");
var Token = require("jsonwebtoken");

// 1. crypto: Generate keypair, PKCS#1 format, PEM encoding
const { publicKey, privateKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', 
    {
        modulusLength: 2048,
        publicKeyEncoding: {type: 'pkcs1',format: 'pem'},
        privateKeyEncoding: {type: 'pkcs1', format: 'pem'}
    });

// 2. Sign verify using the generated PEM keys
var payload = "some payload";
const signed = Token.sign(payload, privateKey, { algorithm: "RS256", keyid: "1" });

const verified = Token.verify(signed, publicKey, { algorithms: "RS256", complete: true });
console.log(verified.payload);
```

Of course, this would also be achievable with *WebCrypto*, but *crypto* is less cumbersome and more comfortable overall. Besides, *WebCrypto* still has the status *Experimental* under NodeJS, s. [here](https://nodejs.org/api/webcrypto.html#web-crypto-api).

---

For extracting n, e, d the keys can be imported and exported as JWK:

```js
// 3. Derive n,e,d
// crypto: Import PEM, export as JWK (the latter is only possible as of v15.9.0)
var pubJwk = crypto.createPublicKey(publicKey).export({format: 'jwk'});
console.log(pubJwk.e);
console.log(pubJwk.n);

var privJwk = crypto.createPrivateKey(privateKey).export({format: 'jwk'});
console.log(privJwk.d);
```

NodeJS supports JWKs only from v15.9.0. For earlier versions, you can apply e.g. [pem-jwk](https://github.com/dannycoates/pem-jwk):

```
// for earlier versions than v15.9.0 apply e.g. pem-jwk for conversion
var pem2jwk = require('pem-jwk').pem2jwk
var pubJwk = pem2jwk(publicKey)
console.log(pubJwk.e)
console.log(pubJwk.n)
var privJwk = pem2jwk(privateKey)
console.log(privJwk.d)
```

---

With the *pem-jwk* library it would also be possible to use the *WebCrypto* code by converting the JWKs to PEM keys (*pem-jwk* supports conversion in both directions). However, due to the experimental status of the *WebCrypto API* for NodeJS and the easier handling of the *crypto* module, this seems to me the less favorable option (although this is of course a matter of opinion).